# Простейший IMAP клиент на winsock C++

Tags: winsock, c++, imap

Добрый день, в общем нужно сделать простейший IMAP клиент на сокетах.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#define BUFSIZE 1024

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{    
    int recvSize=1;
    char buf[BUFSIZE]; 
    char msg[BUFSIZE];
    WSADATA wsda;
    int     sock;
    struct hostent *host;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    short int       s_port = 143;
    const char      *s_ipaddr = "imap.mail.ru";
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsda);
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP);

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(s_port);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(s_ipaddr);

    if(server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr == INADDR_NONE)
    {
        host = NULL;
        host = gethostbyname(s_ipaddr);
        if(host == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        memcpy(&server_addr.sin_addr, host->h_addr_list[0], host->h_length);
    }

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)))
        {
               printf (" Connect error  %d \n ", WSAGetLastError ( ) );
               getchar();
               return -1;
        }
    ZeroMemory(buf,BUFSIZE);
    ZeroMemory(msg,BUFSIZE);
    recv (sock,buf,sizeof(buf),0);    
    cout << buf << "\n";
    cout << "Logging-in:\n";
    ///////// отправляет комманду логин
    strcpy(msg,"a001 LOGIN oksoff ****\r\n");

    send(sock, msg, strlen(msg), 0);

    cout << msg << "\n";
    recv(sock,buf,sizeof(buf),1);

    cout << buf << "\n";

    getchar();
    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();    
    return 0;
}
```

Проблема в том, что после принятия приветствия, сервер не реагирует ни на какие команды, то есть просто ничего не приходит на recv. RFC читал, команды отправляю вроде правильно

http://s017.radikal.ru/i434/1304/5a/e4837f013372.jpg

Comment: А обычным telnet (или netcat) войти на этот IMAP сервер удается?

В конце-концов попробуйте послать NOOP, в любом состоянии сервер должен ответить OK.

--

И еще, попробуйте в  recv() передать последним аргументом (это флаги) 0, а не 1. 

Кстати, в винде флаг 1 - это что?

Comment: Установка 1 помогла, спасибо